# where clause in linq list

Tags: asp.net, linq

H, I have a list of orders and I'm trying to filter this list. So far I have:

```
    Dim orders = _orderController.LoadAll().ToList()
```

which does indeed give me a list of orders which I can display on a gridview.

How could I filter this list to *say*: `where order.referencenumber = "abc123"`

and only give me one order in the list to display in the gridview

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

VB:

```
Dim orders = _orderController.LoadAll().Where(Function(c) c.referencenumber = "abc").ToList();
```

C#:

```
var orders = _orderController.All().Where(o => o.referencenumber = "abc123").ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't like the "O" ..not declared...may be inaccessible to it's protection level.

Comment: That where syntax is used in C#, in VB.Net it is different

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Error is because my solution is C#, not VB. My bad.

Comment: Ok cool that's worked....say a reference number wasn't supplied..and I just wanted to load them all would I just say if txtRef.text <> "" include the where, and if not load the first example?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `Where` clause before your call to `ToList`

```
 Dim orders = _orderController.LoadAll().Where(Function(c) c.referencenumber = "abc").ToList()
```

you should check you the  [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) found in the documentaion